# sticky section at top of one div only

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to display the sticky header at the top of the main content only - ie, as soon as the top of the footer div reaches the top of the window, the sticky section hides.

```
<body>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>CONTENT BEFORE STICKY SECTION</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<!-- our markup -->
<header>
<h1>Sticky Section</h1></header>

    <div class="content" style="background-color:#7BD2D5; height:1000px; padding:200px 20px;"> <!-- this is the area id like to display the sticky section at the top of the page only-->
MAIN CONTENT - SHOW STICKY BAR WHEN THIS SECTION IS IN VIEW

</div>

<div class="fonnter" style="line-height:1000px; padding-top:400px;"><!-- Remove sticky section once scrolled to footer content-->

  <p>FOOTER CONTENT - Hide sticky section at the top of the page</p>

</div>

<script>
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100){  
        $('header').addClass("sticky");
    }
    else{
        $('header').removeClass("sticky");
    }
});
</script>
```

How can I change the > 100 value to look for a div container instead?

Answer (score 0):

Add `sticky` Class In Css & **Jquery 2.1.1**

```
.sticky
{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

**Live Demo** [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/emx1xgby/)

**Snippet Example**

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100){  
        $('header').addClass("sticky");
    }
    else{
        $('header').removeClass("sticky");
    }
});
```

```css
.sticky
{
 position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>CONTENT BEFORE STICKY SECTION</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<!-- our markup -->
<header>
<h1>Sticky Section</h1></header>

    <div class="content" style="background-color:#7BD2D5; height:1000px; padding:200px 20px;"> <!-- this is the area id like to display the sticky section at the top of the page only-->
MAIN CONTENT - SHOW STICKY BAR WHEN THIS SECTION IS IN VIEW

</div>

<div class="fonnter" style="line-height:1000px; padding-top:400px;"><!-- Remove sticky section once scrolled to footer content-->

  <p>FOOTER CONTENT - Hide sticky section at the top of the page</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you actually wanna do is check the `scrollTop()` of the window minus the position of the `footer`.

```
$(this).scrollTop() - $('.footer').position().top
```

However - note that your element has `line-height:1000px; padding-top:400px;` (which I'm not so sure you really need).

I added border to that element (in the example) so you can see exactly what happen:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() - $('.footer').position().top > 0){  
    $('header').removeClass("sticky");
  } else{
    $('header').addClass("sticky");
  }
});
```

```css
header {
  display: none;
}
.sticky {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
.footer {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>CONTENT BEFORE STICKY SECTION</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<!-- our markup -->
<header class="sticky">
  <h1>Sticky Section</h1></header>

<div class="content" style="background-color:#7BD2D5; height:1000px; padding:200px 20px;"> <!-- this is the area id like to display the sticky section at the top of the page only-->
  MAIN CONTENT - SHOW STICKY BAR WHEN THIS SECTION IS IN VIEW

</div>

<div class="footer" style="line-height:1000px; padding-top:400px;"><!-- Remove sticky section once scrolled to footer content-->

  <p>FOOTER CONTENT - Hide sticky section at the top of the page</p>

</div>
```

Comment: although this dose not work as planned, I think the concept is close: So to show sticky header I need to check scrolltop position = main content div and to hide sticky to check scrolltop position = footer tip

Comment: Can you explain what exactly not work as planned? I need to understand the problem in order to help with a fix :)

Answer (score 0):

This might give you some idea,

```
<script>
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var offsetHeight = $('header').offset();
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > offsetHeight.top){  
          $('header').addClass("sticky");  //dynamicall stick header according  to the header height
      }
      else{
          $('header').removeClass("sticky");
      }

     //As soon as footer, reaches window top, remove sticky header.

      var footerOffset = $('#footer').offset();
      if (footerOffset.top == 0){  
           $('header').removeClass("sticky");  //dynamicall stick header according to the header height
      }
      else{
           $('header').removeClass("sticky");
      }

    });
</script>
```